# What can I research for thesis on DNA data storage from math?

Tags: dna, bioinformatics

I'm a math researcher, I just finished a Master on Error Correcting Codes. I recently saw a presentation on DNA-based data storage that I loved.

I wish to continue my studies on (applied mathematics) in this subject.

I received a PhD offer and when I mentioned the subject, the possible director was receptive, but he is not well informed on the subject either, so he proposed that I come up with a research path ...

What do you think is an interesting research topic (and worthy of the community) about storing DNA data from the perspective of error-correcting codes?

Thanks for the help!

Comment: First, I think this question is off topic on a list about biology, as you will see if you take the tour and read the Help on questions. Any answer would be a subjective opinion of what might be interesting. You could try Stack Exchange Bioinformatics instead — you might get more informed opinions there. However I would be very wary of embarking on a PhD on the basis of opinions of unknown people on Q&A list. I can also warn you that a danger of someone in your position is doing a PhD on something that is of absolutely no interest to biologists. You need to find a live senior biologist first.

Comment: This is also duplicate of a question that you have posted on the Bioinformatics Stack Exchange website. https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/questions/4857/what-can-i-research-for-thesis-on-dna-data-storage-from-math

Comment: It is more based in computer science and bioinformatics as data structures and storage of information is using GATC instead of 1 and 0s. Of course, you can probably find some math application since there is math anywhere, but you need to investigate the topic throughly and find an area which could use work.... like any thesis.